# How to convert NSData to CGDataProviderRef on iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, cgcontext, cgimage

I am getting EXEC_BAD_ACCESS errors in a CGContextDrawImage call and trying to trace it back.
I have a PNG image and running a UIImagePNGRepresentation o it gives me NSData instance.

I need to convert this to CGImageRef instance, so I can run the CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider method with this CGImageRef.

I tried two ways:
1) To cast it.

CGImageRef ref = (CGDataProvider)nsdata;

2) To run CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(nsdata);

First case returns empty image, though command doesnt fail.
The reason I tried the second case, even though I have NSData and not CFData is because I remember reading it accepts both.
Whatever be the reason, it is failing due to this.

Is there a way I can use my PNG NSData to create a CGImage that is not corrupted?
Please help.

THanks

Answer (score 9):

Your second try is almost right. CFData and NSData are “toll-free bridged”. Anything that accepts a CFDataRef also accepts NSData (and vice-versa) — you just have to cast correctly.

You need:

```
CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)myNSData);
```

Comment: If you have ARC, Use __bridge to convert directly:
CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)myNSData);

Answer (score 3):

The first is very wrong. You can not turn an `NSData` instance into a `CGImageRef` simply by casting it.

The second should work fine. You will have to cast the `NSData` instance to a `CFDataRef` but that is perfectly legal due to what Apple calls *toll-free bridging*.

Here is another and much easier method:

```
NSData* data = ... get raw image data from somewhere (PNG, JPEG, etc.) ...;
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
```

I prefer to use the higher level `UIImage` methods to load images and then use `image.CGImage` for lower level Core Graphics functions. Don't forget to properly retain the `UIImage` if you need to keep it around.

Comment: `image.CGImage` is definitely better than `(CGImageRef)[(id)CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider((CGDataProviderRef)[(id)CGDataProviderCreateWithNSData((CFDataRef)UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)) autorelease],0,0,0) autorelease]`

Comment: Note that UIKit is not thread-safe, so creating `UIImage` instances on background threads can lead to problems. In some cases it's better to directly create a `CGImageRef`.

Comment: @cheeesus, according to Apple's documentation (https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage), it is safe to create UIImage instances in background threads: *"The immutable nature of image objects also means that they are safe to create and use from any thread."*